# How to setup a fallbackResource in a subdomain

Tags: html, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

My subdomain is http://forma.culturadigital.cc

I have tried the following (from the [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#page-header)):

```
<Directory /kunden/homepages/21/d460086828/htdocs/forma/es>
FallbackResource /forma/es/index.php
</Directory>
```

But i get a 500 internal server error.

Also tried simply:

```
FallbackResource /forma/es/index.php
```

Which doesn't give an error but doesn't catch wrong url's either.

Note: *I have succesfully setup a fallbackResource for the main domain already, like this:*

```
FallbackResource /es/index.php
```

The problem thus, is when trying to make it work in a subdomain.

Comment: How have you defined your virtual hosts? This would be helpful to know which is the best case for handling this in another way.

Comment: i hardly know what a vhost is.. my host is 1and1.es and i haven't seen any .config files in my ftp.. should i try to access this file? im pretty lost

Comment: Do you use the same directory for multiple subdomains?

Comment: no, the folder /forma is only assigned to the subdomain forma.culturadigital.cc

Comment: In that case try to obmit the relative part from your ftp root use the /forma path as root. Basically try using `FallbackResource es/index.php`. Check also if you have a error.log that file may contain helpful informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you told in the comments that the folder /forma is only assigned to the subdomain forma.culturadigital.cc you should try to obmit the relative part from your ftp root use the /forma path as root. Basically try using:

```
FallbackResource es/index.php
```

You could also check if you have a error.log that file may contain helpful informations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `<Directory>` container in an htaccess file. What you should do is create an htaccess file in the `/kunden/homepages/21/d460086828/htdocs/forma/es` directory and put this in it:

```
FallbackResource /forma/es/index.php
```

---

Well, if this is applied specifically to a particular hostname, may as well just use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ /forma/es/index.php [L]
```

Comment: thx, didnt know that, but i have tried your suggestion already and it doesnt work for my subdomain (http://forma.culturadigital.cc) It does work for the folder though (http://culturadigital.cc/forma) but i need it to work on the subdomain

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo can't do that with `FallbackResource`, but you can do something similar with mod_rewrite (see above)

Comment: what @rekire has suggested works for me.. at least so far - not having tested it thouroughly but it does look good i think